# How to designate Python unit tests as having database dependency?

Tags: python, unit-testing, continuous-integration, functional-testing

I am working on a project that has many "unit tests" that have hard dependencies that need to interact with the database and other APIs. The tests are a valuable and useful resource to our team, but they just cannot be ran independently, without relying on the functionality of other services within the test environment. Personally I would call these "functional tests", but this is just the semantics already established within our team.

The problem is, now that we are beginning to introduce more pure unit tests into our code, we have a medley of tests that do or do not have external dependencies. These tests can be ran immediately after checking out code with no requirement to install or configure other tools. They can also be ran in a continuous integration environment like jenkins.

So my question is, how I can denote which is which for a cleaner separation? Is there an existing decorator within unit testing library?

Comment: Your test are classes, right? So how about using inheritance to classify your tests? Inheritance is basically “A *is a* B”. Django does that, btw, to distinguish tests that require different level of database access.

Comment: Marking them is easy - just add a flag to the class. What's best depends on your test pipeline, however. How do you execute the tests? Do you have sets of TestSuites, a custom selection procedure, plain `setup.py`, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define which test should be skipped with the `skipIf` decorator. In combinations with setting an environmental variable you can skip tests in some environments. An example:

```
from unittest import skipIf

class MyTest(Testcase):

    @skipIf(os.environ.get('RUNON') == 'jenkins', 'Does not run in Jenkins')
    def test_my_code(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option.  You could separate different test categories by directory.  If you wanted to try this strategy, it may look something like:

`python
  -modules
unit
  -pure unit test modules
functional
  -other unit test modules`

In your testing pipeline, you can call your testing framework to only execute the desired tests.  For example, with Python's `unittest`, you could run your 'pure unit tests' **from within the python directory** with

`python -m unittest discover --start-directory ../unit`

and the functional/other unit tests with

`python -m unittest discover --start-directory ../functional`

An advantage of this setup is that your tests are easily categorized and you can do any scaffolding or mocked up services that you need in each testing environment.  Someone with a little more Python experience might be able to help you run the tests regardless of the current directory, too.